# Where to place workspace runner while running second FME workspace inside another workspace?

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer, fme-flow-hosted

Case 1 :
[image]
I am facing issue is when I placing `WorkSpaceRunner` at starting it taking all records which is not required but files are getting generated(Output is getting as per expected).

Case 2:
[image]
Another when I place `WorkSpaceRunner` after some processing like `FeatureMerger` its taking required count but files not getting generating might be feature not getting at that place( Output is not generating) ?

As `WorkSpaceRunner` to run for each feature it not ideal to run at starting even if we enable value "Wait for Job to Complete" to Yes. I will be dealing larger shape file datasets. Need to run after finishing current workspace execution.

How can run one time `WorkSpaceRunner` while running inside another Workspace ? If this not possible then where to place ?

Comment: I think you can do with data in a database, but your using files - FME needs to read the entire file before passing data to the next transformer.

Comment: Reading data from shape file. Is it possible once current Workspace finish work then only hit WorkSpaceRunner?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want (run the WorkspaceRunner only once, not a time for every feature) you only have to add a Sampler transformer with 1 first feature.

Comment: any example for this ?